# Modeling Artifacts

Tags: modeling, export, artifacts, obj

[image: 3]I have been modeling a house for the past few days. When I export it, I get these strange artifacts that I can't seem to fix. I've tried cleaning up the mesh and combining vertices by distance, but I still can't seem to fix the problem. Any help would be much appreciated. The photos below are before and after the export. There is a roof component as well as a house model without roof faces because I thought that may have been a culprit. [image: 1]
[[image: 23]

Comment: Do you mean that the first image is what you see in another app? It's not clear... Maybe you need to recalculate the normals (Shift N in Edit mode)?

Comment: Hi, The first image is what I see in preview mode upon exporting. I recalculated normals. Still the same problem. @moonboots

Comment: Could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*", "*help*", "*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 0):

Your model has N-gons (faces that have more than 4 vertices). These don't usually export right. In Edit Mode, if you run `Select > Select All by Trait > Faces by Sides` setting the number of vertices to *Greater Than* 4, Blender will select them for you.

[image: N-gons]

You can manually convert them to tris and quads as shown in the screenshot below, or you can triangulate all of them by clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

[image: No N-gons]

If you try to export now, the model should work. Please note that some exporters have the option to triangulate on export. If the exporter you use supports this feature, try to enable it instead of manually doing the above.